# Search for multiple items in excel and return the entire feild

Tags: excel, powershell, vba

I have an excel file with multiple sheets which are populated with sku and quantity column. I need to search the entire workbook for multiple items and return their quantity. products.txt contains the sku IDs.

```
ABC1234
BCDH214
LDJI983
```

And the Excel workbook, inventory.xlsx contains the following columns

```
**sku**                  ***Quantity***
ABC1234                        2
BCDH214                        0     
LDJI983                        1
```

I would like to run prodcuts.txt against inventory.xlsx and return the quantity of each product.

Can this be done via powershell? or any other way to run this kind of query?

Comment: So, `products.txt` is your main file, and you want to look in Excel (all sheets) for each SKU in the `.txt`, and count the number of times it appears in the excel file?

Comment: Hey! No, I would like to run prodcuts.txt against inventory.xlsx and return the quantity of each product.

Comment: So, for each line in `.txt`, you want to scan all sheets in Excel doc., and add up the numbers in the "Quantity" column that it may have on each sheet?

Comment: yes but not add up the quantity. I would like to see the what is the quantity for each items that are in products.txt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the code shown here [Get Excel data without Excel](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/pstips/2014/06/02/get-excel-data-without-excel/) and ensure you have the [ACE.OLEDB provider](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255) installed.

I created a simple xlsx with:

```
SKU    Quantity
one    1
two    4
three  9
```

Then I called into Excel:

```
$path = 'd:\test\exceldb.xlsx'
$results = Get-ExcelData -Path $path -Query 'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]'

$stuffFromProductsTxtFile = 'one', 'two', 'three'

foreach ($sku in $stuffFromProductsTxtFile)
{
    $results.Rows | Where-Object {$_.SKU -eq $sku} | % {Write-Output "$($_.SKU) has quantity $($_.Quantity)"}
}
```

This gives the following output:

```
one has quantity 1
two has quantity 4
three has quantity 9
```

I think with this, you can change accordingly to whatever you require.

For *completeness*, I have *copied* the sample code from the aforementioned MSDN blog here:

```
function Get-ExcelData {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='Worksheet')]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
        [String] $Path,

        [Parameter(Position=1, ParameterSetName='Worksheet')]
        [String] $WorksheetName = 'Sheet1',

        [Parameter(Position=1, ParameterSetName='Query')]
        [String] $Query = 'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]'
    )

    switch ($pscmdlet.ParameterSetName) {
        'Worksheet' {
            $Query = 'SELECT * FROM [{0}$]' -f $WorksheetName
            break
        }
        'Query' {
            # Make sure the query is in the correct syntax (e.g. 'SELECT * FROM [SheetName$]')
            $Pattern = '.*from\b\s*(?<Table>\w+).*'
            if($Query -match $Pattern) {
                $Query = $Query -replace $Matches.Table, ('[{0}$]' -f $Matches.Table)
            }
        }
    }

    # Create the scriptblock to run in a job
    $JobCode = {
        Param($Path, $Query)

        # Check if the file is XLS or XLSX 
        if ((Get-Item -Path $Path).Extension -eq 'xls') {
            $Provider = 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0'
            $ExtendedProperties = 'Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1'
        } else {
            $Provider = 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'
            $ExtendedProperties = 'Excel 12.0;HDR=YES'
        }

        # Build the connection string and connection object
        $ConnectionString = 'Provider={0};Data Source={1};Extended Properties="{2}"' -f $Provider, $Path, $ExtendedProperties
        $Connection = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection $ConnectionString

        try {
            # Open the connection to the file, and fill the datatable
            $Connection.Open()
            $Adapter = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter $Query, $Connection
            $DataTable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
            $Adapter.Fill($DataTable) | Out-Null
        }
        catch {
            # something went wrong :-(
            Write-Error $_.Exception.Message
        }
        finally {
            # Close the connection
            if ($Connection.State -eq 'Open') {
                $Connection.Close()
            }
        }

        # Return the results as an array
        return ,$DataTable
    }

    # Run the code in a 32bit job, since the provider is 32bit only
    $job = Start-Job $JobCode -RunAs32 -ArgumentList $Path, $Query
    $job | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
    Remove-Job $job
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into it and let you know!

Comment: Great, kindly mark as answer so others who search on this question, see that the question has a solution.

Comment: Hey why am I getting "The term 'Get-ExcelData' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet" all of a sudden. I am using Powershell v5